# Reading from a CSV file into an array

Tags: java, csv, java.util.scanner

I am making a program that has an array of people. The people have different amounts of info for instance they all have a first name, last name, type, gender. The first issue I have is some also have email and some have a image (using Icon) and some have both of them.

I need to read these pieces of data in and then display them, it is for a college class and the teacher was basically like figure it out.. I have read the API and numerous articles and can't seem to get it to work. Can someone give me a push in the right direction?

I am not looking for you to hand me the answers just a little help.

Comment: Consider adding a sample file and code

Comment: Hint: if you know how to read a file one line at a time, just read each line one at a time.  It's a flat file with commas between the fields, and if you are skipping a field, you just have two commas in a row.  Then use split to split the line on the commas, so that you have an array.

Comment: So basically read each line as a string and then split it at the commas?

Comment: Also I was trying this so far...                                                      MemberInterface[] members;
  String memberList = "members.csv";
  File theFile = new File(memberList);
  Scanner input = new Scanner(theFile);
  input.useDelimiter(",");

Answer (score 1):

Read the file line by line and split line with `,`. 
    // you need to create a pojo to hold all the user info.

```
List<UserObject> users = new ArrayList<UserObject>();
try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
         String[] userinfos = line.split(",");
         UserObject newUser = new UserObject();
         //set the mandatory attributes here 
         if (userinfos.length > 4) {
             // you have the extra fields here.
             // set the extra fields to user here
         }
         users.add(newUser);
    }

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

One problem with this is first name or last name might have commas with in them. I suggest you to use any third party csv parser like [Open Csv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: There are ways within Java's api to do all the things I need, I would rather use the API or other ways within java to get this task accomplished. Thank you for the reply!

Comment: Yes, apart from opencsv suggestion, whole method is using only Java API.